# Does non-injective linear transformation guarantee nonzero null space?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I want to prove by contradiction that a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow W$ is one-to-one, can I start the proof with "Assume, to the contrary, that $T$ is not one-to-one. Then there is some nonzero $x \in V$ such that $T(x) = 0_W$"?

I know that for a linear transformation $T$ and its null space N$(T)$, $T$ is one-to-one iff N$(T) = \{0\}$. I also know that the contrapositive of a true statement is also true, so since

*If N$(T)= \{0\}$, then $T$ is one-to-one*

is a true statement, it seems like the following must also be true:

*If $T$ is not one-to-one, then N$(T) \neq \{0\}$*

I'm having some trouble convincing myself that this is true, despite it seeming like a logical conclusion. Why is it guaranteed if there are elements in $W$ with at least two mappings from $V$ that $0$ has to be one of them?

If the argument isn't true, where is my misconception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key property that $T$ possesses is *linearity*: $T(x-y) = Tx-Ty$.

If $T$ *is not one-to-one*, then there exists $(x,y)\in V^2$ with $x\ne y$ so that $Tx = Ty$.  Apply linearity to get $T(x-y) = 0$, so $x-y \in N(T) \setminus \{0_V\}$.  As a result, $N(T)$ is *not* trivial.

---

In general, the implication $P \implies Q$ is equivalent to its contrapositive form $\lnot Q \implies \lnot P$.  Since each of the two implications in the question body is the contrapositive form of another, they are equivalent.

Comment: I think I’m still missing something. If $T(x - y) \neq 0$, doesn’t that imply that $x-y \notin N(T)$?

Comment: @StellaM My bad.  I meant to type $Tx = Ty$: when a function is not 1-1, there exists two _distinct_ points sent to the _same_ value in the image.  Just use linearity to translate that to the origin $0_V$.  Then you'll get your desired conclusion: nontrivial nullspace.

Comment: No worries, I probably should have figured that out from context—but sometimes I see something that doesn’t make sense to me and I tend to fixate unproductively on that one thing. Thank you for making the change, the edited comment was the exact thing I was looking for.